# Evaluating probability as n tends toward infinity

Tags: probability, proof-writing

I feel like this should be a relatively easy proof, but am stumped on how to go about solving it... Any help would be appreciated! Let $S = ${$1,2,\dots,n$}, and let $A,B$ be two random subsets of $S$. Let $\min(A)$ denote the minimum number in the set $A$. What is the probability that $\min(A)= \min(B)$? Evaluate this probability as $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: You will want to consider the probability that $\min(A)=m$ and then that $\min(A)=\min(B)=m$.  Then sum over $m$.  Don't forget the empty subset.

Comment: In what sense are $A,B$ random? This question is meaningless without some kind of distribution. For example, are you just picking a *uniformly* random sizes $a,b$ for sets $A,B$ and then uniformly randomly picking their elements?

Answer (score 2):

How many ways are there to pick a subset $A$ of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ such that $\min(A) = m$? This is the same as picking some subset of $\{m+1,m+2,\dots,n\}$ and adding $\{m\}$. Hence the answer is $2^{n-m}$.

Therefore, the probability that a random subset has minimal element $m$ is
$$
\frac{2^{n-m}}{2^n} = \frac{1}{2^m}.
$$

Summing over all possible values of $m$, the probability that two independent subsets have the same minimal element is
$$
\sum_{m=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2^m}\right)^2 = \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{4^m}.
$$
When $n$ tends to $\infty$, the limit is
$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4^m} = \frac{1}{3}.
$$

Answer (score -2):

Start with $n=2$. Then try it with $n=3$. Look for a link between the two, some sort of pattern. Can you extend the pattern to $n=4$?

Now aim for a general rule for any $n$. Your answer should be in terms of $n$. Then investigate the limit as $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: This answer is useless. It required no thought about the specific problem and could be given as an answer to any question.

Comment: This answer was intended as a strategy. I didn't want to give the answer away. The question asked how they should go about it, not what the answer was.